# Is the number below the same as the repeating decimal of 0.111...?

Tags: calculus

Just heads up, I am a total noob when it comes to maths, so this question might be a lot simpler than I think it is.
And it may end here already as Im not even sure if the following method of constructing a number is reasonable but:

Let's construct a number X (arguable $\in \mathbb{R}$) that has the following properties:

- The integer part consists of a $0$
- The fractional part

  - starts with a $1$
  - ends with a $1$
  - has an infinite amount of $1$s in between the start and end

Is this number X the exact same as $0.\dot1$ (the repeating decimal)

Comment: There is no notion of "end in $1$" after an infinite number of $1's$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, the fractional part "ends with a $1$?"  This doesn't make sense if there are infinitely many decimals.  Anyway, what about $0.\overline{121}?$

Comment: In my mind X is defined as the word YC*C, where Y is the leading '0.' and C is a 1.
So X could be YC^0C = '0.1', or YC²C =  '0.111' etc, (always arguably real numbers) but since its a kleene star I thought it would support any number of C's, even infinitly many.
So I could have an infinite amount of 1s after the decimal seperator, and then one final 1 at the end.

Comment: A tenth of the real numbers between $0$ and $1$ have a $1$ in the first place of their decimal representation and an infinite number of $1$s in other places.  All but one of them are not $\frac19$

Answer (score 1):

X cannot be constructed because the requirement "has an infinite number of 1s between the start and end" cannot be realized. If it has an infinite number of 1s (which is fine in itself), then it cannot have an 'end'.

If you aren't convinced, just ask yourself "What comes after that final 1?"

Answer (score 0):

Your number is $1/9$

Its decimal part is infinitely many $1$ and it does not have a last decimal digit.

It is a good idea to be careful that if you have a last decimal digit then the number of ones are finite.

Comment: oh, so it is fundamentaly impossible that an infinitly big number has a definite or relative first and last place?

Comment: @EyDelf *infinite* suggests no (de)finite end